# Variable being set before object is created javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am building a rails app that uses javascript.  On one of my pages, when the dom is ready, I define a variable to a new `Budget` object.  It seems that the variable is being set before the object is created though and is setting the variable to `undefined`.  I'm using the asset pipeline and not inline javascript if that makes a difference.  Any idea why this is happening?

Here is the line where I set the new variable after the dom is ready

```
(@on_dom_ready_functions ||= []) << "window.budget = new Budget(#{@lead.to_json});"
```

How @on_dom_ready_functions is created/ used

First a partial is created with the domReady function.

```
:javascript
  domReady();
  function domReady() {
    if (!$('dom_ready')) {
      setTimeout(domReady, 10);
      return;
    }
    #{@on_dom_ready_functions.join(" ") if @on_dom_ready_functions}
    #{"$('\#{@focus}').focus();" unless @focus.blank?}
  }
```

Then I render that partial at the bottom of whatever page I need it on

```
= render :partial => 'layouts/dom_ready'
.dom_ready
```

Comment: Is this in a view?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes it is

Comment: How is `@on_dom_ready_functions` is used?

Comment: @Ruslan Just added the code to the question.  Essentially it's a function in a partial that waits for the dom to be ready before it executes the functions it is given.  Then I put the partial at the bottom of whatever page I need it on

Comment: I'd check what gets rendered from the `dom_ready` because it seems like you should be using the `<%= @on_dom_ready_functions.join(" ") if @on_dom_ready_functions %>` to render the variable

Comment: @Ruslan This is what gets displayed in the source.  Is this on the right track? `<script>
  domReady();
  function domReady() {
    if (!$('dom_ready')) {
      setTimeout(domReady, 10);
      return;
    }
    window.budget = new Budget({...});
    
  }
</script>

<div class='dom_ready'></div>`

Comment: So the problem is with the `"window.budget = new Budget(#{@lead.to_json});"`?

Comment: @Ruslan Yeah exactly, I'm trying to have window.budget equal my Budget object so I can use it on the page after a user types into a field, checks a box, etc.

Comment: Try creating it manually in the browser console. Or try to escape javascript `new Budget(#{j @lead.to_json})`

Comment: @Ruslan Sorry if this is a bad question, but could you show me what it would like to escape javascript it?  I'm a little new

Comment: Just add the `j` before the `@lead.to_json`. I doubt it will fix it. Just trying different things

Comment: @Ruslan hmm it didn't seem to work :/ any other ideas?

Comment: Does it actually render `@lead.to_json` to `Budget` parameters?

Comment: @Ruslan yeah I just replaced them with the ... in my comment for brevity

Comment: And no javascript errors are being thrown?

Comment: @Ruslan just the notyperror telling me that it's undefined when I try to call functions within the object